# How to properly store clientId, client secret and OAuth2 token with ReactApp

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I'm building an App which I use ReactJS to build my Client-side and Spring framework for my Server-side setup. What I'm trying to archive is a way to store my ClientId, Client secret and OAuth token since I'm implementing OAuth2 Security on my Server-side

I've been searching for the solution for awhile and here is what I've gotten so far

> 1. Using local/session storage
> 2. Use a Proxy server

The second solution sounds really good for me since the client side won't ever have to know anything about it's id or secret registered with the Authentication server but what I makes me think about is the efficiency of this flow. Will this approach slows down the App since you have to 'proxy' the requests?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the server side code to store the information as well? Then you don't need a second server to act as proxy, nor do you have to store it with the client.

Comment: You lost me here, you know that I need those infomations to access the AuthorizationServer right?

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure what stage of the process you were in. The local/session storage is generally the preferred method and provides a little more seamless option.

Comment: https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet.md

Comment: hey! sorry for late respone, i took a short summer break. thanks for the source link, i will check that out.